# Filter by category

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, filter, frontend

I need to filter out this data components based on which button the user clicks, and in this case i need to map over "jobTitle". And the button needs to sit outside the component.

what about redux in this case?

My Data component looks like this:

```
const WorkState = [
    {
        title: 'the Zeipt factory',
        jobTitle: 'Web developer',
        mainImg: project,
        pic: project2,
        pic2: project3,
        url: "/work/zeipt",
        desc: [
            {
                title: 'Description',
                description: 'Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?',
                tools: 'React, Golang, ReactNative'
            }
        ]
        
    },
```

but the problem is i already uses filter inside my component that structure all my data with URL, which looks like this:

```
const Detail = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
    const url = history.location.pathname;
    const [works, setWorks] = useState(WorkState);
    const [work, setWork] = useState();
    

    //UseEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        const currentWork = works.filter((stateWork) => stateWork.url === url);
        setWork(currentWork[0]);
        
      }, [works, url]);
      console.log(work)
      

    return (
        <>
        {work && ( 
            <Container exit="exit" variants={pageAnimation} animate="show" initial="hidden">
                <Headline>
                <h2>{work.title}</h2>
                <h3>{work.jobTitle}</h3>
                    <Imgwrap>
                        <img src={work.mainImg} alt="main img" />
                        <img src={work.pic} alt="main img" />
                        <img src={work.pic2} alt="main img" />
                    </Imgwrap>
                    <Desc>
                        {work.desc.map((info) => (
                            <Info 
                            title={info.title}
                            description={info.description}
                            tools={info.tools}
                            key={info.title} />
                        ))}
                    </Desc>
                    
                    
                </Headline>
           
            </Container>
           
                     
        )} 
        </>
    )
    
};
```

i've tryed lots of things but never really got this to work

oh and this component is where the button needs to sit, which looks like this:

```
const Work = () => {

  

    return(
        
        <Container exit="exit" variants={pageAnimation} animate="show" initial="hidden">
                <Frame1 variants={slider}></Frame1>
                <Frame2 variants={slider}></Frame2>
                <Frame3 variants={slider}></Frame3>
                <div className="filter">
                    <button>I WANT MY BUTTON HERE :)</button>
                </div>
                
            <Project>
                <motion.h2 variants={fade}>The Zeipt Project</motion.h2>
                <motion.div variants={LineAnimation} className="line"></motion.div>
                <Link to="/work/zeipt">
                    
                    
                    <Hide>
                        <motion.img variants={photoAnimation} src={work} alt="project one"/>
                    </Hide>
                    
                </Link>
            </Project>
            
            
            <Project>
                <h2>Company</h2>
                <div className="line"></div>
                <Link to="/work/company">
                    <img src={work2} alt="project two"/>
                </Link>
            </Project>
            
          
          
            <ScrollTop />
        </Container>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use useMemo instead of the useState hook and chain those.

1. WorkState is the data from redux I presume and you can just access those for your base data.
2. To get your single work, use the useMemo hook to reduce noise:

```
 const work = React.useMemo(() => works.find((stateWork) => stateWork.url === url)}, [works, url]);
```

This will execute if url or works change and will return the first item that it finds. No need to filter.

Now for the second filtered works, you can use the same:

```
const [selectedFilter, setFilter] = React.useState():
...
const filteredWorks = Rect.useMemo(() => works.filter(YOUR FILTER FUNCTION DEPENDING ON THE BUTTON CLICKED),[works, selectedFilter])

Now you only need to pass the setFilter function to Work and update the state there.
```

Comment: hey thanks for answer mate :) but could you please be more spesefic about useMemo? WorkState is not the data from redux. This is so hard to explain tbh. Would be awesome if you had time to help me out in a live matter?

Comment: Sure, join me here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228761/usememo

Comment: @Kruzt Are you there?

Comment: I'm sorry mate, i didnt know you we're to reply so fast, so i went to bed. I hope you will reconsider another meet! I am avalible from now on throughout the day!

Comment: You can do join me in this room @Kruzt

Comment: guess i have to few reputation points to join this room :<

Comment: I dont know, what about we can have a chat here? https://discord.gg/eZfXxxzm